# Customize android google maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps

How far can I go, If I want to redraw the whole screen. For example if I want to redraw buildings with another color, shapes, position and so on, is it possible? I want that, that I can set some attributes of android map, put marker, draw lines and so on, but are there any other Maps, which has global cover of the almost whole world?

Comment: What do you mean by "other maps"? Are you searching for an alternative to Google Maps? Then there would be http://www.openstreetmap.org/ for example. There are a lot more: http://blog.programmableweb.com/2012/03/01/23-alternatives-to-google-maps/

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You may want to read about [TileOverlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileOverlay) and look for Moon map in the Google Play Services maps samples.